# How connect windows phone 8 app to wcf server

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, wcfserviceclient, windows-phone-8-sdk

my wcf server is working, calculator app in the windows phone working. But i dont know how i connect calculate app to wcf server. i only add service referance as it's name Hesap

**WCF SERVER CODES**

**IMatemetik.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
namespace WebServisMatematik16._07._2013
{
   interface name "IMatematik" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMatematik
    {
        [OperationContract]
        decimal top(decimal s1, decimal s2);
        [OperationContract]
        decimal cik(decimal s1, decimal s2);
        [OperationContract]
        decimal bol(decimal s1, decimal s2);
        [OperationContract]
        decimal car(decimal s1, decimal s2);
    }
}
```

**Matematik.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WebServisMatematik16._07._2013
{
    public class Matematik : IMatematik
    {
        public decimal top(decimal s1, decimal s2)
        {
            return s1 + s2;
        }
        public decimal cik(decimal s1, decimal s2)
        {
            return s1 - s2;
        }
        public decimal bol(decimal s1, decimal s2)
        {
            return s1 / s2;
        }
        public decimal car(decimal s1, decimal s2)
        {
            return s1 * s2;
        }
    }
}
```

**WINDOWS PHONE 8 CODES**

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace _17tem13WindowsPhoneHesapMak
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        decimal s1 = 0, s2 = 0, son = 0;
        string islem = "";
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "1";
            Hesap.MatematikClient istemci = new Hesap.MatematikClient();
                istemci.topAsync(s1,s2);
        }

        private void Button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "5";
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "2";
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "3";
        }

        private void Button11_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            s1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            islem = "top";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "+";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void Button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "4";
        }

        private void Button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "6";
        }

        private void Button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "7";
        }

        private void Button8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "8";
        }

        private void Button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "9";
        }

        private void Button10_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "0";
        }

        private void Button12_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            s1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            islem = "cik";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "-";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void Button13_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            s1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            islem = "bol";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "/";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void Button14_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            s1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            islem = "car";
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "*";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void Button15_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            s2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            if (islem == "top")
            {
                son = s1 + s2;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "="+son.ToString();
                textBox1.Text = son.ToString();
            }
            if (islem == "cik")
            {
                son = s1 - s2;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "=" + son.ToString();
                textBox1.Text = son.ToString();
            }
            if (islem == "bol")
            {
                son = s1 / s2;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "=" + son.ToString();
                textBox1.Text = son.ToString();
            }
            if (islem == "car")
            {
                son = s1 * s2;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "=" + son.ToString();
                textBox1.Text = son.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void Button16_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = "";
            s1 = 0;
            s2 = 0;
        }
        // Sample code for building a localized ApplicationBar
        //private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
        //{
        //    // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        //    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        //    // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
        //    appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
        //    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

        //    // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
        //    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
        //}
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="_17tem13WindowsPhoneHesapMak.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- LOCALIZATION NOTE:
            To localize the displayed strings copy their values to appropriately named
            keys in the app's neutral language resource file (AppResources.resx) then
            replace the hard-coded text value between the attributes' quotation marks
            with the binding clause whose path points to that string name.

            For example:

                Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

            This binding points to the template's string resource named "ApplicationTitle".

            Adding supported languages in the Project Properties tab will create a
            new resx file per language that can carry the translated values of your
            UI strings. The binding in these examples will cause the value of the
            attributes to be drawn from the .resx file that matches the
            CurrentUICulture of the app at run time.
         -->

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="Tolga" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hesap makinesi" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button1_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button2_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button3" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button3_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button4_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button5" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button5_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button6" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button6_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button7" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,377,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button7_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button8" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,377,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button8_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button9" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,377,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button9_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button10" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,477,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button10_Click" Height="120" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button11" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="316,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button11_Click" Height="120" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button12" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="316,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button12_Click" Height="120" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button13" Content="/" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="316,377,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button13_Click" Height="120" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button14" Content="*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="316,477,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button14_Click" Height="120" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button15" Content="=" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,477,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button15_Click" Height="120" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.458,0.467"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button16" Content="C" Margin="10,477,326,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button16_Click" Height="120" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="10,117,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>
        <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
            aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
            account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
            if the System Tray is hidden.

            Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
        <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
    </Grid>

    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 emulator executes as a separate device on the network, so you can't call your service in localhost, even if your service and app run on the same machine. So you have to:

- configure your service to receive requests from the external network (adding binding and firewall exception)
- configuring appropriately your service reference on WP8 App

All you need to do is explained in this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).